# timestamp in milliseconds and date range - elasticsearch query string

Tags: date, elasticsearch, lucene, range, query-string

I have a timstamp in milliseconds, like `1645825932144`

I'd like to make a date range query with elastic search query string for being able to get all records whom timestamp is in the last 24h:
`timestamp:[now-24h TO now]`

This does not work as timestamp is in milliseconds and `now` produces strings like `2001-01-01 13:00:00`

Is it possible to achieve this with a cast or something?

I read about [range queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_ranges) and [date math](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math), but did not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to compute the timestamp in milliseconds for now and now-24h so why not do it in your application logic and build the query out of those values?

For instance (in JS),

```
const now = new Date().getTime();
const now24h = now - 86400000;
const query = `timestamp:[${now24h} TO ${now}]`;
```

`query` would contain the following value:

```
timestamp:[1647785319578 TO 1647871719578]
```

**UPDATE:**

PS: I might have misunderstood the initial need, but I'm leaving the above answer as it might help others.

What you need to do in your case is to change your mapping so that your date field accepts both formats (normal date and timestamp), like this:

```
PUT your-index/_mapping
{
    "properties": {
      "timestamp": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
      }
    }
}
```

Then you'll be able to query like this by mix and matching timestamps and date math:

```
GET test/_search?q=timestamp:[now-24h TO 1645825932144]
```

and also like this:

```
GET test/_search?q=timestamp:[1645825932144 TO now]
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm only looking for query string here.

Comment: How do you build your query string?

Comment: By writing it... This is only text. Your answer is absolutely not what I'm looking for. That's why it is a downvote.

Comment: Sorry but your initial need wasn't clearly expressed and I might have misunderstood it. Now, I think I've got it, and updated my answer accordingly, please check it out again.

Comment: Thank you for your update. Yes that can be an option indeed. No way to do this directly from text?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "directly from text". The mapping needs to be changed one way or another and it's an easy operation to do only once. When done, your query can be created as you want it. There's no cast operator in the Lucene expression language

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer, so it is not possible with the Lucene expression language. That's what I was looking for! Extra question now, if the field has already the "type: long", it looks like it is not possible to update the mapping for setting it to "type: date, format: epoch_millis". Is it?

Comment: Indeed, in that case the field is not interpreted as a date and date math is not possible. What you can do, however, is to add a new field (`timestamp2` or whatever) with the appropriate mapping and then run `_update_by_query` on your index with a small script that copies the `timestamp` value in `timestamp2` and index it properly. You'll then be able to run your query on `timestamp2`. The cleaner solution is to reindex your data with the appropriate mapping type for `timestamp`

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what we have done in the end...